# loop thru dates on group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I am trying to display a table(data coming from my DB), which count the occurrence of the data on that date.

I want to group the data by date and then loop thru each date and run the query. The problem is on the server logs I am just getting is an infinite loop of my query.

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data` WHERE (NOT (name = ''))
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data` WHERE (NOT (age = ''))
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data` WHERE (NOT (address = ''))
```

controller:

```
def sum
    date = Data.all
    @sub_date = date.group_by(&:Submit_Date).map
end
```

Model:

```
  def name_null
    Data.where.not("name = ?", '').count
  end

  def age_null
    Data.where.not("age = ?",'').count
  end

  def address_null
    Data.where.not("address = ?", '').count
  end
```

Views:

```
<tr>
        <% @sub_date.each do |l, date|%>
            <td><%=l%></td>
              <% date.each do |ds| %>
                  <td><%= ds.name_null%></td>
                  <td><%= ds.age_null%></td>
                  <td><%= ds.address_null%></td>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
</tr>
```

Pls do tell me where I got it wrong, currently studying rails. :)

Comment: Question is not clear, can you post what are you expecting? what's the input and more

Comment: @Brauie Try this `date.group(:submit_date)`

Comment: hi @vishal what would be the difference by using .group vs group_by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

## controller

```
def sum
    date = Data.all
    @sub_date = date.group_by(&:submit_date)
end
```

## Model

```
  def name_null
    Data.where.not("name = ?", nil).count
  end

  def age_null
    Data.where.not("age = ?",nil).count
  end

  def address_null
    Data.where.not("address = ?", nil).count
  end
```

## view

```
<% @sub_date.each do |l, date|%>
    <tr>
        <td><%=l%></td>
          <% date.each do |ds| %>
              <td><%= ds.name_null%></td>
              <td><%= ds.age_null%></td>
              <td><%= ds.address_null%></td>
          <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: still the same, could it be that the DB I am running my queries are thousands of records?

Comment: have you got data in instance variable `@sub_date` ?

Comment: @Brauie you can try with few records also. In controller, `date = Data.all.take(20)`

Comment: I thought by putting date = Data.all inside @sub_date would do it?

Comment: yeah it work(date = Data.all.take(20)), somehow it stop the infinite looping of my query. I have 160K plus rows of data in my DB.

Comment: you have to add pagination which fetch 10-20 records

Comment: `kaminari` gem is used for pagination. You can integrate it.

Comment: is kaminari better than will_paginate?

Comment: you can use `will_paginate` also